# Will deleting WP's code in .htaccess cause problems?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I need to use the following redirect on my site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} name.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[0-3]) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/2013/12 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$  http://v2.name.com/$1/$2/$3 [NC,R=301]
```

However, it only works if I delete the code Wordpress put in my .htaccess (I've tried putting it both before and after this code with no luck):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What sort of problems is this going to cause if I delete it permanently? And is there some way around this?

Comment: Does it work if you only have one `RewriteEngine On` statement in `.htaccess`?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem like it changed anything.

Comment: One more thing you can try -- in your first code block, change `[NC,R=301]` to `[NC,R=301,L]`. (That *should* tell the rewrite module that this is the last `RewriteRule` for the preceding `RewriteCond`s.)

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `[L]` flag to the `[NC,R=301]` piece (ie, `[NC,R=301,L]`), which tells the RewriteEngine that the RewriteRule is the last one for the block of `RewriteCond`s, apparently solved the problem.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} name.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(1[0-9]{3}|200[0-9]|201[0-3]) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/2013/12 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$  http://v2.name.com/$1/$2/$3 [NC,R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Reference

- Apache's [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and [`mod_rewrite` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (particularly the section on [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule))

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` rules generated by WordPress serve to make it handle arbitrary links (other than those to existing files), which in practice means that they are needed for pretty permalinks functionality.

Without them WP will function, however pretty permalinks feature won't be available and any existing pretty permalinks will be broken.

Comment: Well that doesn't sound good. Is there some other way I can get URL redirect to work then, or does Wordpress just thwart any attempts at redirects beyond what it already does?

Comment: @frodob I rarely deal with these rules to say what might be the issue with one you are trying to add. It should be very possible in principle, since for example static page caching plugins add very extensive rules of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Deleting the code may cause infinite looping.

Comment: This is a little _too_ short for an answer. Please elaborate why and how would that be an issue.

Comment: Sorry Rarst! I dont know how to explain the "why", I just know from trial and error that looping may occur.

Comment: Then the nice start would be to say that it is from your experience and describe said experience. For example it's not even clear what _kind_ of looping you refer to. Looping in PHP code? Looping in HTTP redirects? And so on.

Comment: You are correct. I'll research and then update my respponse.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use permalinks feature then deleting .htaccess file will not cause any problem.